# Jquery animations with Ajax post to php script

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to get my jQuery to work with CSS animations/class changes and working with an ajax post for this logon forum. I am having trouble reworking the JQuery animation script and incorporating the Ajax port for username and password. It does not seem to be posting the login information.

```
<form class="login" action="" method="post" autocomplete="false">
    <div class="group">

        <input id="user" type="username" name="user" class="input" placeholder="Username" required autofocus>
    </div>
    <div class="group">

        <input id="password" type="password" name="password" class="input" data-type="password" placeholder="Password" required>
    </div>
    <div class="group">
        <button>
            <i class="spinner"></i>
            <span class="state">Log in</span>
        </button>
    </div>

    <div class="hr"></div>
</form>
```

Here is the jQuery

```
var working = false;
$('.login').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (working) return;
    working = true;
    var $this = $(this),
        $state = $this.find('button > .state');
    $this.addClass('loading');
    $state.html('Authenticating');
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        cache: false,
        url: "login.php",
        success: function(data) {
            if (data.status == 'success') {
                this.addClass('ok');
                $state.html('Welcome back!');
                setTimeout(function() {
                    window.location = "/index.php"
                }, 4000);
            } else if (data.status == 'error') {
                setTimeout(function() {
                    $state.html('Log in');
                    $this.removeClass('ok loading');
                }, 3000);
            }
        },
    });
});
```

Comment: _“It does not seem to be posting the login information”_ - how did you determine that? And what “jQuery animations” are you talking about, I only see you add classes - so you actually mean CSS animations, _triggered_ via jQuery …?

Comment: And why is this using timeouts to begin with? At that point you don’t know if I actually _successfully_ authenticated myself, yet your script seems to add an `ok` class and display “Welcome back!” in any case … makes rather little sense. This should be handled _inside_ the AJAX callback, depending on what status the server-side script actually returned.

Comment: sorry i was not paying full attention. I edited the script using your suggestions. I know it does not seem to be posting because the index checks session var for "access" which is set to 1 within PHP script upon success off the function. The system works fine with out the jquery function on the login button.

Comment: Maybe the PHP script checks if a specific submit button value is included in the POST data - which will not be the case here, because you are circumventing the normal form submission, and at the time where the form data gets serialized, there is no info available which specific button might have triggered this.

Comment: how do is the login.php ?
Can you post the response of "console.log(data)"

Comment: After using Diego's suggestion and piping the out to the console log I was able to determine that the php function was not returning anything. Adding an echo in with corresponding results resolved my issue along with using 'data' in the if statement instead of 'data.status'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After using Diego's suggestion and piping the out to the console log I was able to determine that the php function was not returning anything. Adding an echo in with corresponding results resolved my issue along with using 'data' in the if statement instead of 'data.status'.